# Background color of UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, background, ios7, xcode5, uinavigationitem

I've got a couple of View Controllers that are added in the 'default Navigation Controller' of Xcode 5. I Want to change the color of the bar, but it doesn't work. This is the code I use:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

This will only change the text in the navigation bar, not the background color. Can anybody  point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this:

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: I Have no header and implementation file for the for UINavigationBar, it's necessary to create this?

Comment: No its not like that. read answer properly.. it is saying that this method does not work

Comment: Right, I see. You happen to know the solution to this ?